# JavaMail Api, Spring framework Could not write content (HTTP)

Tags: java, json, spring, http, jakarta-mail

I am trying to receive messages from Gmail implementing JavaMail Api, using Spring Framework.

When I debug it gets all done well, but at the very end it fails:

```
o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Not connected (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message["folder"]->com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder["store"]-com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore["defaultFolder"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Not connected (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message["folder"]-com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder["store"]-com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore["defaultFolder"])
```

Comment: Instead of a snippet post the full stack trace...

Comment: This is all I get.. before this exception line I have a method call... That is why I cannot understand the problem.. line before:
 INFO  b.c.z.mg.core.impl.MailServiceImpl - getUnreadMail(request=EntityRequest[entity=MailFilter [mailSubject=Top, lastMailRetrievedDate=null], transactionId=string, transparentData={}]) enter ...

Comment: I don't know what "not connected" is referring to in the error message, but make sure you're still connected to the server when you're using the Message object that was returned from the server.

Comment: Problem solved. Nothing special, and I must say very unexpected from my side, as you said the connection was closed when I was using retrieved Message object. The folder has to be opened when you want to get some property out of the message that you get before. Thank you very much.